# With CSS, is there a way to set the height of a line so that it is certain the text will show (and not get hidden at the top and bottom)?

Tags: css

Let's say we don't set the height of a `div`, and show a few words that won't wrap to the next line, then for sure the text will show without the `W` cut off at the top, or the `g` cut off at the bottom.

But what if we need to set it to show just one line of text?

Example of text being cut off:
https://jsfiddle.net/82us6y53/2/

```
#msg {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Lucida Grande", serif;
  width: 400px;
  height: 1em;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

You can set `height` to `1em`, or `1.2em`, or `1.6em`, but how can you guarantee the text won't get cut off?  If you think `1.6em` will work, what if in the font-family list, a font doesn't exist on the PC, Mac, or Ubuntu, and the second or third font is used?  Or what if the designer thinks `1.6em` is too tall, and want it to be less, and what is the minimal height you can set it -- is there a way to find out?

**Update:** I actually saw the height being set in the existing code in the project... I think the intention was to adjust the spacing between that line and the element below it... so I removed the line `height: 32px` or `height: 1em` from the code, and adjusted the padding and margin instead.  But I wonder, what if we need to actually set a height for this element, then is there is way to know for sure the text will all show.

Comment: Do not set the height. Or set `height:auto;`. What about this?

Comment: It looks ok if you not set height. Then why you want to set height? Is it compulsory to set height?

Comment: set `height` = `font-size`

Comment: @Sakura Setting the height same as font-size will even hide the text.

Comment: as @BhojendraNepal stated already https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/82us6y53/3/

Comment: @BhojendraNepal yes, as I understand, SO want if the text is very long, it will show only first line, same as a short text

Comment: @Sakura It will show just one line text because OP is using `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: instead of height, you can use  min-height: 1em; like this https://jsfiddle.net/82us6y53/5/

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you..
Set height to auto only.

```
#msg {
font-size: 32px;
font-family: "Times New Roman", "Lucida Grande", serif;
width: 400px;
height: auto;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `height` property, or set it to `auto` if it is defined due to a previous selector, and then set the `line-height` to something comfortable:

```
#msg {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Lucida Grande", serif;
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap
}
```

[See forked version of your JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rnywub31/).

You could also use `line-height: normal;` but a number value allows for more flexibility in vertical spacing should your designer request more space. The important part is that `height` should not be set—the important value is `line-height`.

Comment: Setting line-height to normal would be okay. But why actually you need to set the line-height?

Comment: Just set height to auto to show text and not cut down from top or bottom. You can set line-height to add space from top or bottom. There is no need to set height for particular range.